# Remove the newline after variable in `puts()` arguments

Tags: ruby, syntax, newline, put

When I execute

```
print("Enter your name: ")
name=gets
puts("\tHello, #{name}.")
```

, I get:

```
    Hello, Fohsap
.
```

How do I move the period (.) up to the first line?

Comment: The newline seems to be part of the contents of `name`. How did you get that value?

Comment: do you get that output in your batch/terminal or on your webpage?

Comment: @waldrumpus I'll add it to the content of the question.  Just a moment, please.

Comment: @p0rter I get that at CMD/terminal (Win).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`gets` will include the newline character in the returned string. To remove that, you can use `gets.chomp`.

Comment: yes +1 to you, also I recommend to read this article with good examples and explanations http://ruby.activeventure.com/tutorial/part_02/user_input.html

Comment: Thanks, Fivell.  Thanks, Waldrumpus.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 You're welcome. For your information, ruby has a built-in `puts` method that seems to be similar to your `put` method.